# Sort by number order in a foreach loop

Tags: c#

I'm making a program which gets me a list, but the list is not in order. I need to list to be in order like...

```
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt
```

However, it's coming out like

```
2.txt
1.txt
3.txt
```

All in random order. I am using

```
foreach (var file in d.GetFiles("*.txt"))
{                 
    tosend = tosend + file.Name + "\n";
}
```

I don't want a single string. After it gets the file name it's going to readtext of other files its set and add it. So like [1.txt] Text

Comment: From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8he88b63(v=vs.110).aspx): *"The order of the returned file names is not guaranteed; use the `Sort` method if a specific sort order is required"*

Comment: And what if the files are `10.txt`, `9.txt` and `1.txt`. What order would you like them in now?

Comment: @EricLippert I want them just counting up

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/248603/natural-sort-order-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 4):

Use LINQ:

```
foreach (var file in d.GetFiles("*.txt").OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList())
{
    ...
}
```

If the files will always be a number.txt you can use

```
foreach (var file in d.GetFiles("*.txt").OrderBy(x => int.Parse(x.Name.Substring(0,x.Name.IndexOf(".txt"))).ToList())
{
    ...
}
```

You will want to add some error checking.

Comment: What is the compelling benefit of the `ToList` ?

Comment: Doesnt quite work right https://gyazo.com/ef640852da17f25259a1440a960a976b

Comment: see the above edit for it not working the way you wanted

Comment: You got your fix in a little faster than I could get it for you, I personally think mine is more readable, up to you. `d.GetFiles("*.txt").OrderBy(f => Int32.Parse(f.Name.Split('.').First())).ToList();`

Comment: The ToList isn't necessary because the foreach loop will force the query to execute (which is why the ToList was probably there). If you remove the ToList you'll see it performs the same.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can sort the array:

```
string[] files = d.GetFiles("*.txt")
Array.Sort(files, StringComparer.InvariantCulture);
foreach (var file in files)
{                 
   tosend = tosend + file.Name + "\n";
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work file string[] files is not valid with system.io

Comment: Hmm..I don't have a way to try it right now, but according to the documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2(v=vs.110).aspx#Examples) it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Use Linq

```
// top of code file
using System.Linq;
```

In method:

```
var files = d.GetFiles("*.txt").OrderBy(file => file.Name).ToList();
```

or as a string as per your example

```
string tosend = string.Join("\n", d.GetFiles("*.txt")
         .Select(file => file.Name)
         .OrderBy(x => x));
```

This joins the returned ordered list of file names using `\n` as a separator.

Comment: I don't want to ToList though. Because there isnt going to be one thing after the tosend. It has to be other things so its all on one line.

Comment: It looks like OP wants a list in a text string not a `List` object.

Comment: @LoganRisen - I added a second example of how you can use linq. Here you get a single string of the file names joined (in order) by `"\n"`.

Comment: @LoganRisen - see Eric's comment though, sorting alphabetically does not work very well when you deal with numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for *Natural sort* i.e.

```
  1.txt
  9.txt
 10.txt
```

you can use *Interop* as a quick (and may be a dirty) solution (see [Natural Sort Order in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248603/natural-sort-order-in-c-sharp) for details)

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

...

[DllImport("shlwapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern int StrCmpLogicalW(string left, string right);

...

// Obtain files
var files = d.GetFiles();

// Sort files in natural order
Array.Sort(files, (left, right) => StrCmpLogicalW(left.Name, right.Name));

// combine files' names into the string
string tosend = string.Join("\n", files);
```

Comment: @BJ Myers: `StrCmpLogicalW` is the function *File Explorer* uses to sort files, but you are quite right: *Interop* is often a dirty solution even if it's quick one.